# sass styling not getting applied when overridden

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

my folder structure

```
 bootstrap 
    all the scss n bootstrap file
 scss 
    _variable.scss
     styles.scss
     styles.css
```

my overidden styles in styles.css

```
 /* this part works

 $body-bg: #f5f5f5;
 $theme-colors: (
        "primary": #ffffff,
        "success": #000000
   );
  $link-color:                #ffffff;
  $link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) ;

 /* this overridden styles dont work */
 .container-fluid{
      .row{
        background-color: #000000;}}                   
  .dropdown{
   &:hover{
 .dropdown-menu{
     visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
     overflow: visible;
  }} }      
.dropdown-menu{
  visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;}
```

/* this overridden styles dont work */

the  **$** variable works and are applied but then the **.container-fluid** dont get applied to my html

```
     <div id="app"  class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar justify-content-start navbar-dark bg-dark ">
                <a class="navbar " href="#">
```

can anyone please let me know where m going wrong m seriously looking out for help

Answer (score 0):

add `!important` to the css you want to apply

```
.container-fluid{
    .row{
        background-color: #000000 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: it still will work with just  background color :) and not to use important  as css specificity